# Starting multiple sessions of Vim using batch files

Tags: session, batch-file, vim

I am having trouble achieving the following using a `*.bat` file:

1. Open in Gvim `file1` and `file2` in one session/progress;
2. Open in Gvim `file3` in another session/progress;
3. Open the URL in default browser: `http://www.bls.gov/soc/major_groups.htm`

However, the following three lines can only invoke one Gvim session.

```
start http://www.bls.gov/soc/major_groups.htm
gvim file1 file2
gvim file3
```

In this specific case, only one Gvim session with `file1` and `file2` loaded would be started. The third line `gvim file3` simply got ignored. In general, the line with `gvim` gets executed if only it is the first line containing `gvim` at the beginning.

Any suggestion in making `1-3` possible through batch file?

Which syntax error am I making?

Comment: You probably need to run gvim in the background. If you closed the first gvim the second would probably open. (How to do this with batch. I don't know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Vim installer adds gvim to your path by adding a gvim.bat file to your system path somewhere. To continue your own .bat file after calling another .bat file, you can't just invoke it by name. You need to use the `call` command:

```
start http://www.bls.gov/soc/major_groups.htm
call gvim file1 file2
call gvim file3
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works and most importantly, does not invoke any extra `cmd` window

Comment: @llinfeng If this answer worked better you might consider accepting it instead of mine.